# TypeError: makeMove() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python-3.x, object, reference

I am getting a weird problem.  I call the same method against instances of a class and they work fine.   But somewhere along the line of running the programs I lose the object reference and now it shows me trying to make a call against my class instead.    Here is what I see in the debugger for a good call:

`<Move.Move object at 0x0000000003F362E8>`  (object reference)

but later I will just get a

`<Move.Move class>`  (class reference)

How am I at times losing my object reference and instead getting a class reference.

Famous last words, I have checked my code against my change files and don't see any changes in this area.

Any thoughts or suggestions are appreciated.

Code as requested.  Hope it helps.

```
for move in moves:
    if move.targetStack is not None:
        t = t+1
        bestMove = move #Just need to have one to compare to

if t==0:
    break
try:
    for move in moves:
        if move.targetStack is None:
            continue
        elif move.highCard.rank > bestMove.highCard.rank:
```

P.S.  This raises AttributeError instead.   But has same cause of referencing the Move class and not an instance.   It works for about 6 full cycles before breaking.

Comment: It is difficult to guess what's happening without you showing how you call the function and what your class looks like. In short you need a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem.   It was a capitalization issue.   In of my cases it was assignin Move (the name of the class) to the variable bestMove.    Sometimes I miss type safe languages!